# Online Investing and Trading Cryptocurrencies, Equities and Options in U.S. Markets

Tags: investing, trading, options, brokerage, cryptocurrency

Would you be so kind and tell me which brokerage services might have fastest website and features (e.g., "limit orders", "stop limit orders", etc.) for trading cryptocurrencies (e.g., from BTC to DOGE), high volatility equities, and put and call options trading in the U.S. markets (e.g., OTC, Nasdaq, NYSE)?

I have looked into Fidelity, which seems that it does not have cryptocurrency trading, and Robin Hood, which is slow and does not seem to be fair and transparent about limit orders and stop limit orders and so on. 
Also, there are others such as Ally, E*Trade, Option House, TDA, Trade Station, IB, Charles Schwab, which I do not have much detail feature information about them.

I'd so much appreciate it if you may provide information, for small accounts (e.g., $25K to $100K) and limit orders, features, and so on. Not looking specifically for product advice or recommendation, since I'm already aware of these services, just not worth logging to each of them and test.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @benmiller - This is one I am inclined to delete. Is there any identifiable way to make this *not* a product/service request? Your objective advice is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of best commission rate, that  depends on the size and style of your trading.

If you trade larger blocks of shares, you're better off at a fixed fee broker that charges say $4.95 to $6.95 per trade (Ally, Fidelity, TD Ameritrade, Trade Station or Schwab). Some of these brokers offer free trades if you maintain certain balances.

If you trade in smaller increments and prefer to scale in and out, tastyworks and Interactive Brokers would be more suitable.

All of these brokers provide limit orders though some offer more complex order algos as well.  They also provide the same access to all US markets be they option or equity, regardless of price.

In terms of other services, that varies from broker to broker:

- Low margin rates
- Portfolio margin
- Research
- Good option analytics
- Quality of charting
- Real time news
- Stable and easy to use trading platform
- Effectiveness  at obtaining borrowable shares for shorting
- Ability of tech support and customer service
- Maker/taker rebates

I have no suggestions for crypto since that's outside of my bailiwick.